# VBA excel macros: Run only from a location

Tags: vba, excel

I have a few Excel sheets with macros which I want any user to be able to run only from a particular location, in my case a particular sharepoint. 
Should a user "SaveAs" the Excel file to any alternative location - he should get an error message.

I am looking for a VBA script to be put in these workbooks to allow me meet my objectives.

Can someone help please?

Comment: This question is off-topic according to the SO guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic . In order for us to help, we need to be able to see the code that is causing the issue.

Comment: My apologies - i am new here & should have familiarized with guidelines before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can there display an error message and set the `Cancel` parameter to true if someone wants to save it to another location.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

If Not ThisWorkbook.Path Like "//sharepoint/path/*" Then
    MsgBox "You can't save the excel", vbCritical
    Cancel = True
End if

End Sub
```

In the same way you can check in the Workbook_Open function if the Workbook is opened in a correct location:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

If ThisWorkbook.Path Like "//sharepoint/path/*" Then
    'Do things
Else
    'Error message and close
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I am not trying to prevent the excel from being saved. I am trying to get macro from being run from a sharepoint only and no where else.

Comment: I edited my answer. I hope I understood what you wanted. I honestly don't know about Sharepoint but the Path of the Workbook should be an URL from Sharepoint so I think you can check that.

Comment: Thanks Wernerson - this answers my question. Much appreciated.

Comment: Glad to help. Could you mark the answer as accepted so that others see it worked for you :)